# How to implement edit selection in tableview as seen in iOS messaging app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uitableview

I want to implement iOS messaging app `Edit` (also seen in the mail app) feature where the user selects the edit button, and then cells move over and the user can select a few cells and then click a button that performs some action(for me I want to save which cells were selected).

[image: http://ios.wonderhowto.com/how-to/11-hidden-features-ios-8s-new-messages-app-for-iphone-ipad-0155476/]  [image: http://ios.wonderhowto.com/how-to/11-hidden-features-ios-8s-new-messages-app-for-iphone-ipad-0155476/]

[From: http://ios.wonderhowto.com/how-to/11-hidden-features-ios-8s-new-messages-app-for-iphone-ipad-0155476/]

I started approaching this problem like it was a simple tableview with editing style but quickly realized that the typical editing approach for table views will not do as it seems to only allow for insertion and deletion.

My code only shows how to make the tableview editable so I don't think it's relevant, but I can provide it if needed. I'm mostly wondering if this is gonna take custom cell work, or is it a built in feature to the public API as a couple google searches revealed nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Well looking at Apple's example seemed to do the trick:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Listings/MultiSelectTableView_APLMasterViewController_m.html

I needed to say

```
TableView.AllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true;
```

and that turns the default editing mode to selection instead of delete or insert